# On click of checkbox enable and disable checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi
i want to enable the the checkboxes again if user has uncheck the checkboxes which was checked. however in my case case the id and name of the element should to be same. checkboxes are getting disabled on the basis of their values and in the same way i want to enable them back...

```
  <input type="checkbox" value="1"  id="preferenceid" name="preferenceid">
  <span>MBA</span>          
  <input type="checkbox" value="2"  id="preferenceid" name="preferenceid">
  <span>Integrated MBA</span>           
  <input type="checkbox" value="3"  id="preferenceid" name="preferenceid">
  <span>MBA/PhD</span>          
  <input type="checkbox" value="4"  id="preferenceid" name="preferenceid">
  <span>Diploma</span>          
  <input type="checkbox" value="5"  id="preferenceid" name="preferenceid">
  <span>BA(Mass Communication)</span>           
  <input type="checkbox" value="6"  id="preferenceid" name="preferenceid">
  <span>BBA</span>




<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#preferenceid[value="1"],#preferenceid[value="2"],#preferenceid[value="3"],#preferenceid[value="4"]').click(function () {
                $('#preferenceid[value="5"],#preferenceid[value="6"]').attr("disabled",true);
            });


        $('#preferenceid[value="5"],#preferenceid[value="6"]').click(function () {
            $('#preferenceid[value="1"],#preferenceid[value="2"],#preferenceid[value="3"],#preferenceid[value="4"]').attr("disabled",true);

        });


           if($('#preferenceid[value="1"],#preferenceid[value="2"],#preferenceid[value="3"],#preferenceid[value="4"]').attr('checked')) {
            $('#preferenceid[value="5"],#preferenceid[value="6"]').attr("disabled",true);
        }

        if($('#preferenceid[value="5"],#preferenceid[value="6"]').attr('checked')) {
            $('#preferenceid[value="1"],#preferenceid[value="2"],#preferenceid[value="3"],#preferenceid[value="4"]').attr("disabled",true);

        }
</script>
```

Comment: The id for an element must be **unique** — you should pay a visit to http://validator.w3.org/ (Oh, and your `span` elements would be better expressed as `label` (with appropriate `for` attributes)

Comment: thanks for your information david..reason is that i have to generate the id's dynamically..

Comment: It still isn't allowed. Generate **different** ids dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

[Disable And Enable Input Elements In A Div Block Using jQuery](http://techchorus.net/disable-and-enable-input-elements-div-block-using-jquery)

look here please.
and don't forget to make element id unique